# Исчезает боковое меню

Tags: дефект, дизайн

| Google Chrome | Microsoft Edge | Windows 10 Домашняя |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Версия 98.0.4758.82 | Версия 98.0.1108.43 | Версия 21H1 |

Если пролистать страницу вниз и навести указатель на любую ссылку, то при возвращении к верхней части страницы исчезнет боковое меню (рис. 1 и 3). Пропажа наблюдается и в режиме инкогнито (рис. 2).

Явление обнаруживается, если прокрутить до слов "Наймите разработчика" (можно и ниже, но не выше). Меню не изменит своего искажённого состояние до тех пор, пока не пошевелится указатель, но если он находился на элементе `left-sidebar`, то состояние изменится при его покидании. Пункты меню исчезают не плавно, а целыми строками (сначала целиком исчезает слово "Главная", затем - "ПУБЛИЧНЫЕ" и т.д.).

Изменение наблюдается даже без авторизации, но для этого необходимо удалить верхнюю панель (рис. 4) (через инструменты разработчика или стандартно - с помощью крестика). Причём выбранный пункт меню исчезает последовательно: сначала - текст, потом - фон (рис. 5).

Предположительно, минимальная высота страницы должна составлять 4814px ([подходящая страница](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)). Но это касается не только страниц определённых вопросов, например, общий список вопросов (50 вопросов на странице) (рис. 6) или страница синонимов меток (рис. 7) тоже подвержены такому изменению.

Обнаружено, что существует некоторая минимальная скорость прокрутки страницы. Если скорости недостаточно, то меню останется видимым. Кроме того, можно добиться такого состояния, что не придётся убирать курсор с ссылки (рис. 8).

| [image: введите сюда описание изображения] | [image: введите сюда описание изображения] | [image: введите сюда описание изображения] | [image: введите сюда описание изображения] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Рис. 1. Исчезает боковое меню | Рис. 2. Проблема сохраняется и в режиме инкогнито | Рис. 3. Наводиться можно даже на ссылку в том же блоке | Рис. 4. Верхняя панель неавторизованного пользователя |

| [image: введите сюда описание изображения] | [image: введите сюда описание изображения] | [image: введите сюда описание изображения] | [image: введите сюда описание изображения] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Рис. 5. Промежуточное состояние исчезновения | Рис.6. Общий список вопросов | Рис.7. Страница синонимов меток | Рис. 8. Интересный результат |

Этот вопрос на MSE: [Side menu disappears](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376132)

Comment: Думаю, стоит добавить информацию об ОС, браузере и его версию. На Ubuntu с Firefox 96.0 не наблюдаю.

Comment: Это на каком-то конкретном вопросе или на любом? У меня на аналогичном Chrome и Win10 Pro не проявляется.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1379485/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b5) тоже возникает. Возможно, это происходит только на достаточно длинных страницах

Comment: Юзер скриптов каких-нибудь не подключено? И, кстати, видео лучше бы перевести в GIF и можно прямо на SO (через imgur) залить.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ нет, было только расширение Avast, но я его отключил и перезапустил браузер, а проблема осталась

Comment: В режиме инкогнито ещё можно попробовать.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ В режиме инкогнито проблема воспроизводится (обновил вопрос)

Comment: Надо репортить на [мета-мету](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat но в этом у меня нет опыта... К тому же, я ещё исследую это поведение

Comment: Просто написать то же, что уже написали сюда, только на английском и с тегом [bug]. Когда закончите исследовать. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat хорошо, спасибо за совет